# How to Hide Payment Cash on Delivery when Pick-up in Store Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I use plugin **Cash On Delivery** in Nopcommerce. But I want to edit the code, that hide Cash on Delivery payment when customer choose Pick-up in store. In the code, I find **HidePaymentMethod**, but I dont know how return true, when customer chooser radio button pick-up in store.
I am using nopcommerce 4.2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Orders;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Payments;
using Nop.Plugin.Payments.CashOnDelivery.Controllers;
using Nop.Services.Configuration;
using Nop.Services.Localization;
using Nop.Services.Orders;
using Nop.Services.Payments;
using Nop.Services.Plugins;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Payments.CashOnDelivery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// CashOnDelivery payment processor
    /// </summary>
    public class CashOnDeliveryPaymentProcessor : BasePlugin, IPaymentMethod
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly CashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings _cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings;
        private readonly ILocalizationService _localizationService;
        private readonly IPaymentService _paymentService;
        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;
        private readonly IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;
        private readonly IWebHelper _webHelper;


        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        public CashOnDeliveryPaymentProcessor(CashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings,
            ILocalizationService localizationService,
            IPaymentService paymentService,
            ISettingService settingService,
            IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService,
            IWebHelper webHelper)
        {
            _cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings = cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings;
            _localizationService = localizationService;
            _paymentService = paymentService;
            _settingService = settingService;
            _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
            _webHelper = webHelper;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Process a payment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="processPaymentRequest">Payment info required for an order processing</param>
        /// <returns>Process payment result</returns>
        public ProcessPaymentResult ProcessPayment(ProcessPaymentRequest processPaymentRequest)
        {
            var result = new ProcessPaymentResult { NewPaymentStatus = PaymentStatus.Pending };

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Post process payment (used by payment gateways that require redirecting to a third-party URL)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="postProcessPaymentRequest">Payment info required for an order processing</param>
        public void PostProcessPayment(PostProcessPaymentRequest postProcessPaymentRequest)
        {
            //nothing
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a value indicating whether payment method should be hidden during checkout
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cart">Shoping cart</param>
        /// <returns>true - hide; false - display.</returns>
        public bool HidePaymentMethod(IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart)
        {
            //you can put any logic here
            //for example, hide this payment method if all products in the cart are downloadable
            //or hide this payment method if current customer is from certain country
          return _cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings.ShippableProductRequired && !_shoppingCartService.ShoppingCartRequiresShipping(cart);



        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets additional handling fee
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cart">Shoping cart</param>
        /// <returns>Additional handling fee</returns>
        public decimal GetAdditionalHandlingFee(IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart)
        {
            var result = _paymentService.CalculateAdditionalFee(cart,
                _cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings.AdditionalFee, _cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings.AdditionalFeePercentage);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures payment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="capturePaymentRequest">Capture payment request</param>
        /// <returns>Capture payment result</returns>
        public CapturePaymentResult Capture(CapturePaymentRequest capturePaymentRequest)
        {
            var result = new CapturePaymentResult();

            result.AddError("Capture method not supported");

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Refunds a payment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="refundPaymentRequest">Request</param>
        /// <returns>Result</returns>
        public RefundPaymentResult Refund(RefundPaymentRequest refundPaymentRequest)
        {
            var result = new RefundPaymentResult();

            result.AddError("Refund method not supported");

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Voids a payment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="voidPaymentRequest">Request</param>
        /// <returns>Result</returns>
        public VoidPaymentResult Void(VoidPaymentRequest voidPaymentRequest)
        {
            var result = new VoidPaymentResult();

            result.AddError("Void method not supported");

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process recurring payment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="processPaymentRequest">Payment info required for an order processing</param>
        /// <returns>Process payment result</returns>
        public ProcessPaymentResult ProcessRecurringPayment(ProcessPaymentRequest processPaymentRequest)
        {
            var result = new ProcessPaymentResult();

            result.AddError("Recurring payment not supported");

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancels a recurring payment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cancelPaymentRequest">Request</param>
        /// <returns>Result</returns>
        public CancelRecurringPaymentResult CancelRecurringPayment(CancelRecurringPaymentRequest cancelPaymentRequest)
        {
            var result = new CancelRecurringPaymentResult();

            result.AddError("Recurring payment not supported");

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether customers can complete a payment after order is placed but not completed (for redirection payment methods)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="order">Order</param>
        /// <returns>Result</returns>
        public bool CanRePostProcessPayment(Order order)
        {
            if (order == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(order));

            //it's not a redirection payment method. So we always return false
            return false;
        }

        public IList<string> ValidatePaymentForm(IFormCollection form)
        {
            var warnings = new List<string>();

            return warnings;
        }

        public ProcessPaymentRequest GetPaymentInfo(IFormCollection form)
        {
            var paymentInfo = new ProcessPaymentRequest();

            return paymentInfo;
        }

        public override string GetConfigurationPageUrl()
        {
            return $"{_webHelper.GetStoreLocation()}Admin/PaymentCashOnDelivery/Configure";
        }

        public Type GetControllerType()
        {
            return typeof(PaymentCashOnDeliveryController);
        }

        public override void Install()
        {
            var settings = new CashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings
            {
                DescriptionText = "<p>In cases where an order is placed, an authorized representative will contact you, personally or over telephone, to confirm the order.<br />After the order is confirmed, it will be processed.<br />Orders once confirmed, cannot be cancelled.</p><p>P.S. You can edit this text from admin panel.</p>",
                SkipPaymentInfo = false
            };

            _settingService.SaveSetting(settings);

            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.DescriptionText", "Description");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.DescriptionText.Hint", "Enter info that will be shown to customers during checkout");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFee", "Additional fee");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFee.Hint", "The additional fee.");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFeePercentage", "Additional fee. Use percentage");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFeePercentage.Hint", "Determines whether to apply a percentage additional fee to the order total. If not enabled, a fixed value is used.");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.ShippableProductRequired", "Shippable product required");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.ShippableProductRequired.Hint", "An option indicating whether shippable products are required in order to display this payment method during checkout.");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.PaymentMethodDescription", "Pay by \"Cash on delivery\"");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.SkipPaymentInfo", "Skip payment information page");
            _localizationService.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.SkipPaymentInfo.Hint", "An option indicating whether we should display a payment information page for this plugin.");
            base.Install();
        }

        public override void Uninstall()
        {
            //settings
            _settingService.DeleteSetting<CashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings>();

            //locales
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.DescriptionText");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.DescriptionText.Hint");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFee");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFee.Hint");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFeePercentage");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.AdditionalFeePercentage.Hint");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.ShippableProductRequired");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.ShippableProductRequired.Hint");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.PaymentMethodDescription");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.SkipPaymentInfo");
            _localizationService.DeletePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.SkipPaymentInfo.Hint");

            base.Uninstall();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a name of a view component for displaying plugin in public store ("payment info" checkout step)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>View component name</returns>
        public string GetPublicViewComponentName()
        {
            return "PaymentCashOnDelivery";
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properies

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether capture is supported
        /// </summary>
        public bool SupportCapture => false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether partial refund is supported
        /// </summary>
        public bool SupportPartiallyRefund => false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether refund is supported
        /// </summary>
        public bool SupportRefund => false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether void is supported
        /// </summary>
        public bool SupportVoid => false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a recurring payment type of payment method
        /// </summary>
        public RecurringPaymentType RecurringPaymentType => RecurringPaymentType.NotSupported;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a payment method type
        /// </summary>
        public PaymentMethodType PaymentMethodType => PaymentMethodType.Standard;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether we should display a payment information page for this plugin
        /// </summary>
        public bool SkipPaymentInfo => _cashOnDeliveryPaymentSettings.SkipPaymentInfo;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a payment method description that will be displayed on checkout pages in the public store
        /// </summary>
        public string PaymentMethodDescription
        {
            get
            {
                return _localizationService.GetResource("Plugins.Payment.CashOnDelivery.PaymentMethodDescription");
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shipping method is saved as a `GenericAttribute` of the current customer. So, you can get via `IGenericAttributeService` (if you don't inject it in your PaymentProcessor class, you have to inject it). If we assume that the system name of your intended shipping method is "Nop.Shipping.PickupInStore", then we can hide the payment method like this:

```
public bool HidePaymentMethod(IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart)
{
    var customer = cart.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Customer != null)?.Customer;
    ShippingOption shippingOption = _genericAttributeService.GetAttribute<ShippingOption>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.SelectedShippingOptionAttribute, _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
    var shippingMethodSystemName = "Nop.Shipping.PickupInStore";

    if (shippingOption!= null && shippingOption.ShippingRateComputationMethodSystemName.Equals(shippingMethodSystemName))
        return true; 

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but I get NullReferenceException, here the image: https://i.imgur.com/Yqp2Ur9.png

Comment: I removed the plugin and install new code, but still not working :(

Comment: Dont forget to build the plugin again after updating the code. Sometimes iis or iis express cache the assembly files.

Comment: I did try at all. I thinks shippingOption = _genericAttributeService.GetAttribute<ShippingOption> dont get the value.

Comment: Yes, most of the time it is `null`. This section prevend errors because of this: `shippingOption!= null`

Comment: I posted the issue in Nopcommerce forum. One guy say that GetAttribute dont find a match

Comment: You don't update the code! I updated the code section yesterday and fix this issue. Please check the code section of my answer again.

Comment: I updated the code, I published the plugin. I tried run in debug mod, when I run to step  ShippingOption shippingOption = _genericAttributeService, then get NullReferenceException message. The code not run to the exception.

Comment: Could you share the full exception message please? I checked the code and it runs successfully

Comment: https://anotepad.com/note/read/e87hhf6m. Here is full exception message

Comment: Well, the code is still not updated. Please do these steps: 1. Rebuild your plugin, if it possible, debug the `HidePaymentMethod` and make sure it works properly. 2. If you publish your code on a server, restart the application after replacing the plugin files. It has to work properly.

Comment: I tried rebuild on local but not working, then I tried upload to server, but cant install a plugin. I get  this message on view Log: The plugin "Payments.CashOnDelivery" not installed. Can you share me your CashOnDeliveryPaymentProcessor.cs class? I dont know where issue :(((